# How to add a close button to the iframe in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an iframe which opens as a popup on a button click however the only way to close it or collapse it is to click outside the window. Instead I needed a close button on top left corner of the popup which allows the user to close the window instead of clicking somewhere outside the window to close it. Can anyone help to achieve this please?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div  style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">
    <iframe allowfullscreen frameborder="1" style="width: 960px; height: 720px; position: relative; left: -50%;"
        [src]="embedUrl | urlSanitizer" id= {{embedId}}>
    </iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from "ngx-bootstrap/modal";
@Component({
  templateUrl: './chart-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart-viewer.component.css']
})
export class ChartViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  code:any;
  embedUrl:string='';
  embedId:string ='';
  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  closeModal() {
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
  }
}
```

Comment: check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsome%2Fsome.component.html

Comment: This is a modal isn't it?

Comment: Can you maybe post your full code on Stackblitz or here? Otherwise its hard to help you or understand the whole issue

Comment: Is there any way of adding a close button to the iframe?

Comment: Should the question be "how to add a click event in Angular": https://angular.io/guide/event-binding ? You may need to use `*ngIf` to conditionally appear elements in DOM: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: You can't put a close button on any iframe, no matter if angular or not. You can put a general button somewhere on the page to toggle / remove an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Just position an  element behind your iframe, style it with position:absolute and position it above the iframe just as you want it.

Make sure they are placed inside the same container element which is styled position: relative or position: absolute to make sure your top/left positioning of the button is in-line with the iframe position

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe></iframe>
  <button (click)="closeModal()"></button>
</div>
```

Styling Example:

```
    .container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    
    .container iframe {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .container button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 10px;
    }
```